# Is there anyway to retrieve an Instagram image identifier from the CDN link?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

For example, I have [this link](https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xpf1/t51.2885-15/e15/11203181_428518084023131_1319862140_n.jpg), and would it be possible to get a link like so: https://instagram.com/p/5PiBAQOwBt/ from it?

Answer (score 0):

From https://instagram.com/p/5PiBAQOwBt/ you can get image link from `source code of page`:

`<meta property="og:image" content="https://igcdn-photos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpt1/t51.2885-15/10005419_943595429032221_1267327891_n.jpg" />`

But, if you have just image link, only image searching by Google (etc.) helps to find `canonical url`.

In `Instagram API` use [media](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/) `endpoint` to get both links.